# Как организовать вывод нескольких textView Android

Tags: android, android-textview

Как организовать вывод нескольких textView друг за другом. Т.е у меня есть несколько textView и я хочу выводить их друг за другом, с возможностью переноса на новую строку.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду, под "есть несколько textView"? Они уже созданы и просто нужно их разместить или должно быть динамическое создание этих textView?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov Да я создаю TextView в цикле из-за того что разные вывожу слова в них, мне надо организовать вывод слов с автоматическим переносом на новую строку.

Comment: Могли бы вы код прикрепить, как вы их создаете?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы создаете `textView` в цикле, то можете в конце ваших слов добавлять экранированный символ `\n`.

Пример в вашем случае(если Java):

```
for(){
  ...
  textView.setText("Some text\n");
  ...
}
```

Лучше конечно посмотреть в сторону `RecyclerView` - это будет более правильно. Если вдруг задумаетесь, вот отличный tutorial - [ссылка на статью](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465).